# Para que serve a interrogação no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Citando um exemplo:

```
         if(this.gap > 1 || !this.sorted)
         {
            this.sorted = true;
            this.gap = parseInt(this.gap / 1.3) == 0 ? 1 : parseInt(this.gap / 1.3);
            setTimeout(this.name + '.comb_sort_acending_order(0);', this.speed);
         }
```

Esse ponto de interrogação (`?`)  significa o que?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É um **operador condicional**.

Do [developers.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators):

> Operador condicional
>
> O operador condicional é o único operador JavaScript que utiliza três
>   operandos. O operador pode ter um de dois valores baseados em uma
>   condição. A sintaxe é:

```
condicao ? valor1 : valor2
```

> Se condicao for verdadeira, o operador terá o valor de valor1. Caso
>   contrário, terá o valor de valor2. Você pode utilizar o operador
>   condicional em qualquer lugar onde utilizaria um operador padrão. Por exemplo:

```
var status = (idade >= 18) ? "adulto" : "menor";
```

No caso do seu exemplo, se `parseInt(this.gap / 1.3) == 0` então `this.gap`será 1, senão será `parseInt(this.gap / 1.3)`.

Comment: Esquece o que eu disse antes, realmente a escrita é JavaScript, todavia o resto tava certo XD. Até mais